# python: sampling without replacement from a 2D grid

Tags: python, algorithm, random, python-3.x

I need a sample, without replacement, from among all possible tuples of numbers from `range(n)`. That is, I have a collection of (0,0), (0,1), ..., (0,n), (1,0), (1,1), ..., (1,n), ..., (n,0), (n,1), (n,n), and I'm trying to get a sample of k of those elements. I am hoping to avoid explicitly building this collection.

I know `random.sample(range(n), k)` is simple and efficient if I needed a sample from a sequence of numbers rather than tuples of numbers.

Of course, I can explicitly build the list containing all possible (`n * n = n^2`) tuples, and then call `random.sample`. But that probably is not efficient if `k` is much smaller than `n^2`.

I am not sure if things work the same in Python 2 and 3 in terms of efficiency; I use Python 3.

Comment: Tuples are sequences, so your sentence "needed a sample from a sequence of numbers rather than tuples of numbers." makes no sense. To you mean you need a sample from a sequence of tuples? It's unclear in that case how these tuples look.

Comment: Your code (`random.sample(range(n), k)` works and is correct for all sequences, tuples, lists, strings and any subclass of `collections.Sequence`.  Did you try your code yet?  What's the question?

Comment: @Regebro: 'a sample from tuples' = 'a sample of k tuples out of a sequence of n tuples'. 'a sample from a sequence' = 'a sample of k elements out of a sequence of n elements'. I'm going to edit the question to clarify.

@S.Lott: what I meant is that I can't refer to a sequence ((0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)) as a simple `range` on which I can simply apply `sample`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how many of these you're selecting, it might be simplest to just keep track of what things you've already picked (via a `set`) and then re-pick until you get something that you haven't picked already.

The other option is to just use some simple math:

```
numbers_in_nxn = random.sample(range(n*n), k) # Use xrange in Python 2.x
tuples_in_nxn = [divmod(x,n) for x in numbers_in_nxn]
```

Comment: I think that you meant `random.sample(range(n*n),k)` because that's what I was writing up when I realized that you had put this part in.

Comment: +1 The second option seems perfect to me (after replacing `n * n` with `range(n*n)`, and `100` with `n`). I can't think of when drawing from a set could be better, given that `sample` is claimed to be highly efficient.

Comment: You can replace `(x % n, x // n)` with `divmod(x,n)`.

Comment: +1 for clever answer (and understanding what the OP wanted, apparently). Would also be good in Python 2.x if `range` was changed to `xrange`.

Comment: @Kabie, `divmod(x,n)` would return `(x // n, x % n)` not `(x % n, x // n)`, so it's not exactly the same, although I don't think that matters here (and therefore also think @J.F. Sebastian's comment is irrelevant).

Comment: Added `divmod` (forgot that existed), added note about `xrange` (but since the OP had specified Python 3, I wrote the original code for that :)).

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Of course, I can explicitly build the
>   list containing all possible (n * n =
>   n^2) tuples, and then call
>   random.sample. But that probably is
>   not efficient if k is much smaller
>   than n^2.

Well, how about building the tuple *after* you have randomly picked one? Ie, if you can build the tuples before you randomly choose which one to pick, you can do the picking first and building later.

I don't understand how your tuples are supposed to look, but here is an example, although I realize your tuples are all of the same length, this shows the principle:

Instead of doing this:

```
>>> import random
>>> all_sequences = [range(x) for x in range(10)]
>>> all_sequences
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> random.sample(all_sequences, 3)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

You would do this:

```
>>> import random
>>> selection = random.sample(range(10), 3)
>>> [range(x) for a in selection]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Without trying (no python at hand):</strike>

```
random.shuffle(range(n))[:k]
```

see comments. Didn't sleep enough...

Comment: That doesn't give tuples in `n` x `n`, because it would never give, say `(1,1)`.

Comment: But then what does "without replacement" mean? Ah, now I see. k distinct tuples of length n.